# can't send token from function to another function

Tags: php

I want to change password using `sql`. i take a token from an url like this:

http://localhost:8001/app/changepass?&token=nsfrvomltz

i use `GET method` to get that token "nsfrvomltz" from the url:

```
if(isset($_GET['token'])){
    $token = $_GET['token'];
}
```

Then i send it to another function with the new password:

```
$this->userModel->changepass($newPass, $token)
```

This function is inside another class which i have access using a controller:

```
public function changepass($newPass, $token){
        $this->db->query("UPDATE users SET password = :newPass WHERE token = :token");
        $this->db->bind(':password', $newPass);
        $this->db->bind(':token', $token);
        if($this->db->execute()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is the token goes empty to this function even if i used `GET method`, so the query doesn't work and the password doesn't change.

The `$newPass` has the value, but token still empty. i don't know why.

I appreciate any kind of help.

UPDATE:

I use another function to send an email to the user:

```
public function forget($email){
         $this->db->query('SELECT token FROM users WHERE email = :email');
        $this->db->bind(':email', $email);
        $res = $this->db->single();
        $message = "Please click on this link to change your password:
http://localhost:8001/app/changepass?&token=$res->token";
        mail($email, "Forget password", $message, "From: app");
        if($this->db->execute()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The email is received and the user click on the link, then he write the new password.

after this he click on "ok" button but the password doesn't change.

Comment: Did you check while passing the token, is it present in url?

Comment: yes it is @RobinSingh

Comment: can you show your proper code where and how you pass the token

Comment: please check the above update @RobinSingh

Comment: Looks like everything is ok in your code

Comment: yes @RobinSingh but still doesn't work!

Comment: I recommend using a call to `file_put_contents` with flag `FILE_APPEND` at various points to log the value of `$token` to see where it becomes empty.

Comment: _1)_ The current link is: `.../changepass?&token=...`. Remove the ampersand character ("&"). _2)_ What does this line return: `$res = $this->db->single();`, in the method `forget()`? Add the following lines after it: `var_dump($res);` and `var_dump($res->token)` and show us the result by reediting your SO question.

Comment: I suppose, by clicking on the "OK" you are submitting the "change password" form with the POST method. Even though you're reading the _token_ from the `$_GET` array, you must send it further as a `$_POST` item, like the new password. Maybe there lies the problem?

Comment: thanks @dakis. Now i read the token using a Session variable.  if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
                    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
                    unset($_SESSION['token']);
                } and everything is ok now. it works perfectly

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Good luck further.